# What is the maximum rated power of a flip-flop?

Tags: power, digital-logic, flipflop

This is the link towards the D FF datasheet I am working with: [SN74LVC1G80](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lvc1g80.pdf)
My ambient temperature of working is 100C. Operating temperature for DBV package is -40C to 125C.

Junction-to-ambient thermal resistance = 243.4 C/W (for DBV package).

Intention is to find the maximum rated power of the device, following is the method used:

Range from ambient temperature to maximum operating temperature = 125C -100C = 25C.

Maximum rated power = (Above Calculated Range)/Junction-to-ambient thermal resistance = 25C/(243.4C/W) = 102.7 mW.

Kindly confirm or correct the above method used to calculate the maximum rated power calculation.

Or how to do the maximum rated power calculation if there is no rated power information in the datasheet.

Comment: That assumes that the local ambient (around the chip) doesn't rise with heat from the chip.

Comment: Basically @Andyaka's response means that you assumed an ideal heat sink at the package. You need to calculate with the thermal resistance from the package to the "air" as well.

Comment: This also assume no margin for MTBF which may be improved with a heat sink

Comment: How will you cause this high internal power dissipation?

Comment: @HorrorVacui, thermal resistance from the package to the air, Is this a standard value normally found in datasheet?

Comment: @vt673 read the data sheet again in the thermal section and note that you are probably better using junction to board thermal resistance - then read the linked document under the table to see how this works. Also please explain how you think you are going to produce a power dissipation of over 100 mW.

Comment: @Andyaka, Linked document is informative. Regarding the 100mW power,  Intention is to conclude the power dissipated in the IC is lesser than the rated power. But that rated power of the chip was not there in the datasheet. So was trying to find a way to calculate the rated power. Basically a try.

Comment: OK so you have a way forward?

Comment: Yes, My understanding is need to add 'Junction-to-board thermal resistance' with 'Junction-to-ambient thermal resistance'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most folk would assume that the chip is adequately soldered to a PCB that will conduct heat away without much of a local temperature rise (maybe a couple of degrees). So, use the "junction to board thermal resistance" (77.6 °C/W) and read the linked document (Semiconductor and IC Package Thermal Metrics application report) listed on the data sheet to understand how this works.

Comment: For me adding Junction-to-board thermal resistance' with 'Junction-to-ambient thermal resistance' seems more accurate. Apologies if this is an oversight.

Comment: They don't add in series, they add in parallel just in case you thought otherwise.